# DataGridview Combobox display from datasource

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

[FORM IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCzmz.png)

I have two tables in my database

1. datatable
2. kar

datatable have two columns Product, Producttype. kar table also have two columns type, tax.

In my form I have a Datagridview with 3 columns Productname, type, tax.

Productname column is datagridviewcomboboxcolumn which display all the product from datatable.    `

```
public Form5()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form5_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.datatableTableAdapter.Fill(this.myBillDataSet.datatable);
        dataGridView1.EditingControlShowing += new DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventHandler(dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing);

    }

    private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox combo = e.Control as ComboBox;
        if (combo != null)
        {
            combo.SelectedIndexChanged -= new EventHandler(ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
            combo.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
        }
    }
    string item = null;
    private void ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ZEE-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyBill;Integrated Security=True");

        ComboBox cb = (ComboBox)sender;
        item = cb.Text;
        if (item != null)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Producttype from datatable where product=@pro", con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pro", item);
            con.Open();
            string val = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            con.Close();


            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select tax from kar where type=@pro2", con);

            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pro2", val);
            con.Open();
            string val2 = cmd2.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            con.Close();
        }

    }
```

when user select any product from dropdown the type and tax column will display the value. I am getting the values but not able to display in gridview cell

Comment: ExecuteScalar only gets one column from the database.

Comment: I want only one column value. my problem is i want that value to next column of datagrideview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly insert value in your cells inside ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged event using column index

```
dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[YourCellindex] = val;
dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[YourSecondCellindex] = val2;

dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);
dataGridView1.EndEdit();
```

Hope It helps